# Correct XML annotations. Java. JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, annotations

There is a structure. I want to link the three entities in this way: the Company should contain id, name of company and the list of Departments, each Department has a list of Workers, id and name of department. Each worker has name, id.

```
+Company
-int companyId
-String companyName
-Set<Department> listOfDepartments = new HashSet<Department>();

+Department
-int departmentId
-String departmentName
-Set<Worker> listOfWorkers = new HashSet<Worker>();

+Worker
-int workerId
-String workerName
```

My attempt:

Company

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Entity
public class Company {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int companyId;
    private String companyName;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="listOfDepartments")
    @XmlElement
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Department> listOfDepartments = new HashSet<Department>();

    public Set<Department> getListOfDepartments() {
        return listOfDepartments;
    }

    public void setListOfDepartments(Set<Department> listOfDepartments) {
        this.listOfDepartments = listOfDepartments;
    }

    public Company(){}

    public Company(String companyName){
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name="id")
    public int getCompanyId() {
        return companyId;
    }

    public void setCompanyId(int companyId) {
        this.companyId = companyId;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="companyName")
    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }
```

Department

```
@Entity
public class Department {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int idDepartment;
    private String departmentName;

    @XmlAttribute(name="companyId")
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name="companyId")
    private Company company;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="listOfWorkers")
    @XmlElement
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Worker> listOfWorkers = new HashSet<Worker>();

    public Set<Worker> getListOfWorkers() {
        return listOfWorkers;
    }

    public void setListOfWorkers(Set<Worker> listOfWorkers) {
        this.listOfWorkers = listOfWorkers;
    }

    public Department(){}
    public Department(String departmentName, Company company){
        this.departmentName = departmentName;
        this.company = company;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name="id")
    public int getIdDepartment() {
        return idDepartment;
    }

    public void setIdDepartment(int idDepartment) {
        this.idDepartment = idDepartment;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="departmentName")
    public String getDepartmentName() {
        return departmentName;
    }

    public void setDepartmentName(String departmentName) {
        this.departmentName = departmentName;
    }
```

Worker

```
@Entity
public class Worker {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int idWorker;
    private String workerName;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="departmentId")
    private Department department;



    public Worker(){}
    public Worker(String workerName,Department department){
        this.workerName = workerName;
        this.department = department;
    }

    public Department getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(Department department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name="id")
    public int getIdWorker() {
        return idWorker;
    }

    public void setIdWorker(int idWorker) {
        this.idWorker = idWorker;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="name")
    public String getWorkerName() {
        return workerName;
    }

    public void setWorkerName(String workerName) {
        this.workerName = workerName;
    }
}
```

I catched the error:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 3 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Class has two properties of the same name "companyId"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public int ru.eldarkaa.dto.Company.getCompanyId()
        at ru.eldarkaa.dto.Company
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private int ru.eldarkaa.dto.Company.companyId
        at ru.eldarkaa.dto.Company
Class has two properties of the same name "companyName"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String ru.eldarkaa.dto.Company.getCompanyName()
        at ru.eldarkaa.dto.Company
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.lang.String ru.eldarkaa.dto.Company.companyName
        at ru.eldarkaa.dto.Company
Class has two properties of the same name "listOfWorkers"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.util.Set ru.eldarkaa.dto.Department.getListOfWorkers()
        at ru.eldarkaa.dto.Department
        at private java.util.Set ru.eldarkaa.dto.Company.listOfDepartments
        at ru.eldarkaa.dto.Company
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.util.Set ru.eldarkaa.dto.Department.listOfWorkers
        at ru.eldarkaa.dto.Department
        at private java.util.Set ru.eldarkaa.dto.Company.listOfDepartments
        at ru.eldarkaa.dto.Company
```

GODs of XML Annotations please advise me a solution.

Comment: have you tried removing '@XmlAttribute(name="companyId")' from Department.java?

Answer (score 0):

By default JAXB treats public fields and properties as mapped.  When you annotate a non-public field it causes that to become mapped as well resulting in the conflict.

**Solutions**

- Annotate the property (get or set method) instead of the field (instance variable).
- Annotate the field and the class with `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html